# Write text and then write background image depending on Y end point axis of text PHP

Tags: php, gd

So right now I have some code that create one big image our of writing a bunch of individual images (GD PHP).

As of right now I have to write the background...

```
imagefilledrectangle($comp, 20, 20, 760, $descriptionHeight+900, $grey);
```

Then write the text...

```
imagettftext($variable, $font, 0, 350, 105, $color, $type, "Location: $city, $state");
```

Problem is that there is a bunch of text to write and the background height will vary depending on if not there is text there to be written.  I am keeping a dynamic Y axis variable so when all the text gets done writing I have the end point of the text.

Is there any way to write a bg after all the text as been written to the main image?  If not is there an ideal solution out there to accomplish a dynamic background?

Any help or thoughts would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: would it work to draw out the background assuming the greatest height, write the text then crop the image to truncate what you don't need?

Comment: @Orangepill Not sure how I would go about doing that.  Right now I have a function that gets the dimensions of the text and returns a y variable.  But I have to do this for 5 different sections and seems redundant coding to do a function for each section.

Comment: can you post out some target images somewhere ... I feel like i'm missing something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make one pass through all your texts and calculate the dimensions of your image using [imagettfbbox()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettfbbox.php). Then create the image, draw the background and go through your texts once more, this time actually drawing them on the background.

Comment: Yea right now I have a function that does that.  Prob is I have to do it for like 5 different sections and it just seems redundant to do it that way.  Didn't know if there was an easy trick to write a bg under all the layers.

Comment: I think this can be done using ImageMagick, but I've never used it from PHP. Basically, you'd make a transparent image with your text and then create the image with the background and merge the two.

Answer (score 0):

So just to update what I wound up doing was making two different functions for each block.  The first function in the series of functions would get the size of the block and then in another set of functions write the bg and content for the block.  It seems redundant but it works best in my case especially since the block height will vary depending on how much content is in each one.

Thanks for all the ideas and input.